# Re-size Text Area onFocus with JQuery in Dynamically generated Table

Tags: php, jquery, html

I am trying to achieve the effect of re-sizing the Text Area after user clicks in it. For some reason the following code works only for the very first row of the data table. The data table is generated dynamically and displays data from DB query.

The flowing code is the code for generating table, with text area field `id=txtArea`:

```
echo "<td ><textarea size=4 name=WinterFollowUp id='txtArea' rows=2     cols=12 >$row[WinterFollowUp]</textarea></div> </td>";
```

this is the jQuery script that I have:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#txtArea').focus(function(){
        $(this).attr('rows', '10');
    });
});
$('#txtArea').blur(function(){
    $(this).attr('rows', '2');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the id is unique in jquery , so jquery will find the first textarea with that id , if you want 
to apply to all textarea you must specify a class or only textarea

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('textarea').focus(function(){
    $(this).attr('rows', '10');
   });
});
$('textarea').blur(function(){
   $(this).attr('rows', '2');
});
```